# Create second child in Firebase database

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I've created a simple application, where you click a button, and it posts the value to a Firebase database. Code is below...

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var button: Button


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    }

    fun SUCCESS(view: View) {
        val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        val myRef = database.getReference("Value")
        myRef.setValue("One")
        
    }

}
```

But when I click the button again, it just overwrites the previous entry (or child). How would I create a function that creates a second child in the database? I'm still doing research on this, so sorry if it has already been posted!!

Comment: Just use a different child name other than "Value"?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use two differently named keys, you'd do what Doug commented:

```
val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
val myRef = database.getReference()
myRef.child("First").setValue("One")
myRef.child("Second").setValue("Two")
```

If you want to have any number of child nodes, you'll want to use `push()`:

```
val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
val myRef = database.getReference()
myRef.push().setValue("One")
myRef.push().setValue("Two")
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [working with lists of data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data).

Comment: This creates two values simultaneously. I've answered my own question, probably at the same time you commented! lol! But it raises more questions! lol

Comment: I clarified the first snippet to show how to do the equivalent while determining the child node names yourself.

Comment: Thank you! ...but this still creates two childs simultaneously. One with the name "First" and value of "One" and one with the name of "Second" and value of "Two."

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! This is kind of what I want... but it poses the question of how to create a specific value for push, instead of random letters. I guess this will do for now.

```
fun SUCCESS(view: View) {
        val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        val myRef = database.getReference("Value")
        myRef.push().setValue("One")
     }
```